# How do you calculate the breakeven amount for two credit cards with different fees and rebates?

Tags: finance

> Credit Card (CC) M offers a rebate of cash back of $a$  dollars, with NO annual fee.
>   CC S offers a rebate of cash back of $b$  dollars, but charges an annual fee of $f$.
>
> How much must I spend with CC S to breakeven with CC M, to ensure my regaining $f$ and the advantage in choosing CC S for its higher $b$?

Call total spending $s$. Then I need: Rebate Revenue from CC S = Rebate Revenue from CC M

$\iff bs - f = as \iff s = \dfrac{f}{b-a}$.

For the following quote,  $a = 0.02, b = 0.04, f = 129$. Then my work yields: $s = \dfrac{f}{b-a} = \dfrac{129}{0.02} = 6450/$year $ \iff \color{green}{\$537.5}$/month.
But [the quote beneath](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/top-premium-cash-back-credit-cards-in-canada.htm)'s breakeven spending is $\color{red}{\$470}$/month? Thus who is correct?

> 1. Scotia Momentum Infinite Visa ([link](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/go/ScotiaMomentumInfinite))
>
> Right now, this is my favorite premium credit card out there due to the huge $4\%$ cash back that they offer on gas and grocery spending.  In fact, if you spend more than $\color{red}{\$470}$/month in gas/groceries then this card will offer you more cash back than the free $\color{purple}{\text{[MBNA]}}$ Smart Cash card $\color{purple}{\text{[with 2% cash back on gas and groceries]}}$ (assuming \$129/year for $\color{purple}{\text{[Scotia]}}$ primary and secondary card).
>
> In addition to the 4% cash back, they offer 2% on drug store and recurring payments, then 1% on everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are correct. If we are just trying to determine the breakeven total spending, we can use this equation:
$$
s - bs + f = s - as
$$
Substituting the appropriate values in ($b = 0.04$, $f = 129$, and $a = 0.02$) gives us your result of $6450$/year or $537.5$/month.